# Reformatting a secondary hard drive while keeping some files

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I'm almost certain that I'm in a deadlock here. Just recently, my Synology NAS died. So I decided to configure an Ubuntu server instead on an old computer I had laying around. Ubuntu is now installed on `sda`.

I popped in the 1TB Synology drive (`sdb`) and with `mdadm` I'm able to mount and access my files. Now, what I basically want to do is get rid of the entire fs that the Synology used (it's kinda annoying to have to use mdadm, and I'd like an ext4 instead of FAT, which the NAS used), keeping ~700 GB of the data on the disk. However, sda is only ~100 GB.

So: Is it possible for me to get in a state of having a "freshly formatted" secondary 1TB drive without losing my files?

Comment: Well, only by copying files from `sdb` to somewhere else, then reconfigure `sdb` with plain partitions and ext4 and copy back the files. No chance to do this on the fly.

Comment: @Thomas - so based on my current setup, that'd be impossible?

Comment: Yes, you cannot format from FAT to ext4 without moving the data. If you change the format of a drive or partition, you have to backup and restore the data. There is no way of conversion, at the time of this writing.

Comment: Darn it. What I expected, though. Need to get a hold of an external HDD I guess

Comment: You could shrink the FAT partition (~300). Create an ext4 partition from available space (~300). Move as much as possible over. Shrink the FAT further (~300). Expand the ext4 further (~300). Move files from FAT to ext4 and so on until everything moved. But that would be both tedious and risky. Something could go wrong upon when you risk loosing all data.